# Why do I keep getting this 'no module named utils' error?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, importerror

I tried importing factor_analyzer in Jupyter notebook. But I got this error that says 'no module named utils' I recently switched from Python 3 to 2; never had this issue with Python 3. How do I fix this? - Samuel Duraivel [image]

Comment: Why are you switching back to 2? And if this is a new Python installation, why are you expecting it to have the module in question?

Comment: Checking the manual https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/factor-analyzer/latest/factor-analyzer.pdf  and github page https://github.com/EducationalTestingService/factor_analyzer, it says it requires python 3.4 and higher. Check if this might be helpful. Best Regards

Comment: I was getting a 'kernel.dll' error with Python 3. I re-installed the .dll and changed the path environment, but the issue did not get fixed; so, I had to switch back to Python 2.  And no, this is not a new Python installation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `utils` module is not installed on the system.  Try installing it with pip :

```
python -m pip install utils
```

Answer (score 0):

i also faced same problem (import error)while trying to import different modules in python 3.7,so what i did is i just uninstalled the python 3.7 and installed new version of python which is 3.8 and i can able to import my modules without errors,so try using latest version....

Answer (score 0):

utils.py and utils folder could be utilities code written for specific purpose. So it is advised to copy it from the repo to the root of your project folder.